# Loop in R through variable names with values as endings and create new variables from the result

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach

I have 24 variables called empl_1 -empl_24 (e.g. empl_2; empl_3..)
I would like to write a loop in R that takes this values 1-24 and puts them in the respective places so the corresponding variables are either called or created with i = 1-24. The sample below shows what I would like to have within the loop (e.g. ye1- ye24;  ipw_atet_1 - ipw_atet_14 and so on.

```
ye1_ipw <- empl$empl_1[insample==1]
ipw_atet_1 <- treatweight(y=ye1_ipw, d=treat_ipw, x=x1_ipw, ATET =TRUE, trim=0.05, boot = 2)
ipw_atet_1
ipw_atet_1$se

ye2_ipw <- empl$empl_2[insample==1]
ipw_atet_2 <- treatweight(y=ye2_ipw, d=treat_ipw, x=x1_ipw, ATET =TRUE, trim=0.05, boot = 2)
ipw_atet_2
ipw_atet_2$se

ye3_ipw <- empl$empl_3[insample==1]
ipw_atet_3 <- treatweight(y=ye3_ipw, d=treat_ipw, x=x1_ipw, ATET =TRUE, trim=0.05, boot = 2)
ipw_atet_3
ipw_atet_3$se
```

coming from a Stata environment I tried

```
 for (i in seq_anlong(empl_list)){ 
  ye[i]_ipw <- empl$empl_[i][insample==1]
ipw_atet_[i]<-treatweight(y=ye[i]_ipw, d=treat_ipw, x=x1_ipw, ATET=TRUE, trim=0.05, boot =2
}
```

However this does not work at all. Do you have any idea how to approach this problem by writing a nice loop? Thank you so much for your help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `lapply` :

```
result <- lapply(empl[paste0('empl_', 1:24)], function(x) 
                treatweight(y = x[insample==1], d = treat_ipw, 
                            x = x1_ipw, ATET = TRUE, trim = 0.05, boot = 2))
```

`result` would be a list output storing the data of all the 24 variables in same object which is easier to manage and process instead of having different vectors.

Comment: In case anyone will read this with a similiar problem with result_df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(result), nrow=length(result), byrow=T)) you can store all the results in a dataframe. Package for ipw estimation was casualweights